# Deadly slow I/O operations from VM (Win2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-vsphere

I faced very strange behaviour of VM with Windows 2003 OS. This VM is running on our corporate VmWare server (like vSphere or such), I cannot control VM itself, I can only connect guest OS and work with it. I can only see a version of VmWare Tools installed on VM = 10.0.9-3917699, not sure how to guess version of VmWare product behind it.

This VM was working fine for years and suddenly all download operations begin to fail (for any protocol!).

When I open console to VM (RDP or NetSupport), I can copy files **to VM** from network shares - that works fine.

But any I/O operation **from VM** became deadly slow and finally fail after 1-4 kb downloaded. Absolutely all download operations - http/https, ftp, filesystem. I can understand when 1 or 2 protocols has problems but the case when **all protocols** have the same problem - that looks weird! So, files can be copied into VM but files cannot be copied from VM. The bad thing - this is our build machine, so I need to download build results from there. Thus, I can resync sandbox on VM, that works because it is copying data to VM, but after I got build results - there is no way to take it from VM...

However, I noticed one interesting effect. When connected via NetSupport console, I can activate "File Transfer" action and try to download file from there. But I found that **only when I moving a mouse inside VM** then downloading in "File Transfer" works. When I stop moving a mouse it stop to download and finally it fail. For example, when I need to download 120Mb of generated install package I have to sit on it and move mouse for 30-40 minutes to make download works - that is really weird... :-
I could think that VM is configured to stop working when no user input happens. But that is not the case, because I can run sandbox synchronization and close console to VM, it will work fine in backgropund.

Our support team have no idea - what is that and how to resolve? So, I need at least a hint - what to check to figure out a reason of such strange behaviour. How is that possible that any kinds of I/O operation from VM are failing?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have no access to the hypervisor, you can't do anything at all; you can't even gather settings or diagnostic data that could actually allow someone here to have a clue about what is happening. This question as is is unansverable.

Comment: You __will__ need the support of the host's admin(s) as this is (most likely) not a Windows 2003 problem by itself.